# The table "" for active record class "" cannot be found in the database

Tags: mysql, yii

i am using Yii framework. currently i face error i.e. The table "brokers" for active record class "Brokers" cannot be found in the database. but my model and table both exist. i cant understand how this error occure. please help.

Comment: It is difficult to debug a problem when you don't have any code. You should post at least the model code, the code calling it, and the full error with backtrace, and possibly anything else you might think is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your server space or reset your database schema

Comment: Oh it's my server space issue thanks for ur help. please let me khow one more things that how i reset my database schema